# Help with combining sed commands (syntax)

Tags: sed, scripting

I have a file containing many lines, like so

```
, foo = $true
, foo = $false
foo = $true, <--- single space after comma
foo = $false, <-- single space after comma
```

To replace these strings I can do

```
#!/bin/bash

sed -i 's/, foo = $true/bar/g' file
sed -i 's/, foo = $false/bar/g' file
sed -i 's/foo = $true, /bar/g' file
sed -i 's/foo = $false, /bar/g' file
```

or, chain them which is just as bad

```
sed -i -e 's/, foo = $true/bar/g' -e 's/, foo = $false/bar/g' -e 's/foo = $true, /bar/g' ... file
```

But is there a way to use a single sed command to perform all of the iterations?

```
sed -i 's/[,\ ].*foo = [$false\|$true][,\ ]/bar/g' file
```

Comment: That's not adequate sample input to test against since it doesn't include cases like `, foo = $true` multiple times on 1 line, nor ```, foo = $true, ``` (blanks on both ends), nor `barfoo = $true,`, nor `, foo = $falselyAccused`, etc. It's always trivial to match the strings you want and far harder to not match the strings you don't want. Really think about all the possible rainy day cases and post concise, testable sample input **and expected output** that covers all of them if youd like help coming up with a robust script to handle all those cases. Include context around the strings to match

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -Ei 's/,{,1} {,1}foo = \$(true|false),{,1} {,1}/bar/g' file
```

```
sed -Ei 's/(, ){,1}foo = \$(true|false)(, ){,1}/bar/g' file
```

`-E` flag activates extended regular expressions, which allow the
use of `(){}|` metacharacters without escaping.

- `(, ){,1}` matches from 0 (implied) to 1 occurrences of `,` .
- `\$(true|false)` matches `$true` or `$false`.

---

Bear in mind that

```
sed -i -e 's/, foo = $true/bar/g' -e 's/, foo = $false/bar/g' -e 's/foo = $true, /bar/g' ... file
```

is a single sed command, but with various scripts (one for each `-e` flag).

Comment: At least for GNU `sed`, among others, you don't need multiple `-e` you can just do `sed 's/foo/bar/; s/baz/bad/; s/biz/boz/'` and so on.

Comment: @terdon Nice remark, thanks. And [POSIX specifies it](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html): "Editing commands other than {...}, a, b, c, i, r, t, w, :, and # can be followed by a semicolon, optional blank characters, and another editing command."